# Is there a parameter substitution syntax for file or directory existence?

Tags: zsh, variable-substitution

I would like to use parameter substitution to compute a path based on

1. a variable being defined
2. a first default directory to be used if it exists
3. a file inside the $HOME directory to be used if neither of 1 or 2 are available.

The variable (#1) and the file in $HOME (#3) are easy:

```
${KEEPER_HOME:-$HOME/.keeper}
```

But is there a parameter/variable substitution syntax in Zsh for #2?  If we imagined that `||` did this, I would be looking for something like this:

```
${KEEPER_HOME:-$HOME/.config/keeper||$HOME/.keeper}
```

Of course I can do it with `test` inside `$(`...`)` but I am hoping that something more concise and readable exists.

Comment: For (2), you need to do a test for existence, and I don't see how this can be done implicitly by a parameter expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only uses parameter expansions, but it's two lines:

```
glob=($HOME/.config/keeper(N/))
result=${KEEPER_HOME:-${glob:-$HOME/.keeper}}
```

The `glob=` line uses the `/` glob qualifier to check for the directory. The `N` qualifier turns on `nullglob`, so the variable will be empty if the directory doesn't exist.

There may be a way to move the globbing into the nested parameter expansion, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: In Zsh, the coding convention is to use UPPERCASE only for scalar environment variables. Don't use uppercase for local parameters or arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [null glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to check for this existence of files (including directories):

```bash
% print /etc(N)
/etc
% print /foo(N)
```

This works inside parameter expansions, too, when passed as arguments:

```bash
% print ${:-/etc(N)}
/etc
% print ${:-/foo(N)}
```

If you want to use null glob when *assigning a scalar,* then you will need to use [`$~`glob substitution](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) when expanding the parameter:

```bash
% tmp=${:-/foo(N)} 
% print $tmp
/foo(N)
% print $~tmp

%
```

Alternatively, you could use an array instead:

```bash
% tmp=( /foo(N) )
% print $tmp

%
```

However, for your exact case, I’d recommend using an `if` statement, since it makes the code easier to read:

```bash
# Check if string is zero.
if [[ -z $KEEPER_HOME ]]; then
  local default=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-~/.config}/keeper

  # Check if dir exists.
  if [[ -d $default ]]; then
    KEEPER_HOME=$default
  else
    KEEPER_HOME=~/.keeper
  fi
fi
```